# SSAS Process Cube error "We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available."

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ssas, cube

I can't process my cube because of the following errors.
"The following system error occurred:  We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device is connected to your organization's network and try again. If you previously signed in on this device with another credential, you can sign in with that credential. "

I turned on windows and sql logging in server. I am using logging with specific windows user name and password.